# CSS how to maintain position in every device

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap but I turn off the responsive. 
I try to maintain my div position even it's in other device (not responsive).

Screenshot 1 normal version (1366 * 768):

[image: normal]

Screenshot 2 in nexus 10 render:

[image: nexus]

As you can see in nexus 10 the range between right and left become further.

Here is my html code:

```
<div class="topbar">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left pull-left menu-nav">
            <li><a href="index.html" class="logo">Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html" class="logo">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html" class="logo">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right site-logo">
            <li>
                <img src="http://www.underconsideration.com/brandnew/archives/facebook_2015_logo_detail.png" alt="" class="logo-img">
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my css:

.container {
        width:100%;
    }

```
.logo-img {
    max-height: 45px;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.topbar {
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}

.topbar .topbar-left {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 240px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.menu-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding: 35px 0;
    max-width: 35%;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0 35px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 7999;
}

.menu-nav li {
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000;
}


.site-logo{
    display: block;
    float: right;
    padding: 35px 0;
    max-width: 35%;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 0 35px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 7999;
}

.topbar .topbar-right {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    width: 240px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.navbar-default {
    background: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 0px;
    border: none;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want the distance between the two top `<ul>`s to be always the same on all devices?

I have a few suggestions:

- Have a look at [viewport units](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units). It let's you set element's size based on the size of user's viewport.
- Maybe you could use just standard `%`, I don't know what's you usecase.
- Do you set `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` in your HTML header? It set's you viewport size based on devices pixel density. More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: I've already have meta port. `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0, maximum-scale=0, user-scalable=no">` but I still can't keep the distance between those two.

Comment: If I set the intial scale and maximum scale to 1,, it become very close to each other